# Javafx tableview comboboxtablecell filter

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview, uitableview

Please if any one know is it possible to add filter feature to comboboxtablecell in an editable tableview, the problem i have is that i have an editable tableview with a combobox in a column and the amount of data populated in combobox is huge (near of 25500 items) so it's hard for a user to seek an item in the combobox so i was wondering if it's possible to add filter feature to comboboxtablecell.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Wrap the data in a [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) and update the predicate for the filter when the combo box changes value.

Comment: Thank you James_D for your answer, i still have a wondering about where the user will write the filter caracters, in a standard combobox i use a custom tooltip for filtering so the user can see the filter caracters that he writes but in a comboboxtablecell can i have the same. i'm new to javafx and i'm sorry if my questions are not corrects.